# Accessibility Label for radio button on action?

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

In `TableViewCell`, I have custom imageview which act as a radio button. This imageview has two states

1. Selected
2. Not Selected

[image]

By default I have given, Accessibility label as "Selected Checkbox" and "checkbox". Now I want to speak voice text as "new item selected" when it selects and "item deselected" when deselected.

Can we give all four different label? How can I get the same.

Updated: I tried using

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification,@"text")
```

but it skips the text which need to speak.

Comment: Hi Sandy. As per some of the edits I've made on your posts, there's no need to add "Any help", "Please help me", etc. Readers know you need help, and to the native English speaker, this sort of addition may read as a form of begging and pleading, which in turn can attract downvotes. We like succinct here anyway!

Comment: @Sandy : a response to your problem = https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667678/3825084

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you are attempting to do here but I'll try to provide an alternative way of making this accessible.

Instead of treating each radio button as either selected or deselected would it not be better to treat the entire group of radio buttons as one combined accessibility element.

So if you have radio buttons for `[cat, dog, rabbit, guinea pig]`. Then your accessibility should read something like...

`Animal selection group: none selected`

or

`Animal selection group: rabbit selected`

etc...

Having said all of that... what is this UI you are trying to create?

Radio buttons are fundamentally not a part of iOS. It would be a much better alternative to use UI that users know. And then by doing this you make your accessibility issue a non-issue.

Perhaps a `UIPickerView` or a `UITableView` might be better alternatives to radio buttons?

Comment: So as per the updated image. Now things can be clear now I guess. I have given accessibilityLabel for checkboxes. But along with that, I want "string" to be spoken by Voiceover when user tap to select or deselect it. is it possible or right way to do it?

Comment: @Sandy the standard iOS way of doing this type of selection is to provide a place to put some data. You tap it and a tableview is presented. Then when you tap the table view it is dismissed and the data is populated in the previous screen. Go into Contacts and add a phone number to a contact. Then change the type of phone number. It pops up a table where you select the type.

Comment: I did not understand your last comment. Please explain.

Comment: @Sandy open the contacts app on your phone. Edit a contact to add a phone number. Change the type of that number. That is the standard way of doing this UI.

Comment: I agree with you. But What I have is what I need to implement. If you can answer to specific my question that would very helpful to me.

Comment: Your update doesn’t change my initial answer. Treat the whole group as an accessibility group. Not each radio button as a separate thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159076/discussion-between-sandy-and-fogmeister).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you exactly want to do.

**My assumption:** You want to generate sound on click of a button for tableviewcell and also changing the image of Imageview at the same time while checking the state of it (selected or non-selected).

***** do it inside your customTableViewCell class...

- create IBOutlets in .h or .m for your 3 items from customtableviewcell xib.
- create boolean flag to maintain current state (selected or non selected) of that cell.
- create IBaction selector(method) to get event(touch up inside) of button click. Inside this method write code which checks following.

BOOL selectState; //Make this Global in classfile

```
if(selectState) // selected state YES

{
        xyzImgView.image = //Your Non selection Image;
        selectState = !selectState;

        //Play your sound for Non selection

}
    else // selected state NO
    {
        xyzImgView.image = //Your selection Image;

        selectState = !selectState;

        //Play your sound for selection

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

// Considering you have an IBOutlet to checkBoxButton

checkBoxButton.accessibilityLabel = checkBoxButton.isSelected ? "selected" : "not selected"
checkBoxButton.accessibilityHint = checkBoxButton.isSelected ? "" : "Tap to select"